# vSphere WebServervice API get VirtualMachine Details

Tags: java, web-services, vmware, vsphere

I need to get some details about a VirtualMachine like the VM Name, the DNS Name, the Resourcepool and the Host via the vShpere API.

I found a way to search for the VM but I don't know how I can get this details.

Has anyone done this?

Thanke you

Stephan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    //    you can find this code to get some ResourcePool infomation 

          ComputeResource cresource = (ComputeResource) host.getParent();
                    ResourcePool[] resourcepools = cresource.getResourcePool().getResourcePools();


   // if you find a way to search one vm .so  you can write below code. 
    ServiceInstance si = null;
    si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(
                            "https://"+hostVal+"/sdk"), usernameVal,
                            passwordVal, true);
    VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) new InventoryNavigator(
                                    si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntity(
                                    "VirtualMachine", VM_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get VM information by following this approah

1. Get Service Instance
2. Get root folder from service instance
3. Search for Virtual Machine using vmname in root folder

`Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
InventoryNavigator inventoryNavigator = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder);
vm = (VirtualMachine) inventoryNavigator.searchManagedEntity(VirtualMachine.class.getSimpleName(), vmName);`